# Retain the size of Subview added to a scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to add a subview to a `ScrollView` on a single tap. As the content scale of my ScrollView is more than one, the 'Subview' appears to be small. When zoom in of the scroll view happens, I make use of the `setTransform` function to reverse the zoom effect of the scroll view to make the size of the 'Subview' to appear constant. But the issue is when the Subview is added, it appears to be small. So what needs to be done to make the Subview appear at normal size the moment when it is added?

Thanks.

Comment: You've said *when* the issue is, but not *what* it is!

Comment: @hatfinch I have edited the question now, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're calling `-setTransform:` from `-scrollViewDidZoom:`? Why not just call it the same way immediately after adding the subview?

Comment: Yeah, somehow it did not occur to me. It just worked after calling setTransform function after adding the subview. Thanks for reminding :)